# Android M permission of the tested READ_PHONE_STATE(dangerous permissions)

Tags: java, android, mobile, permissions

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher when im trying to get phone number using **getLine1Number()**:

*java.lang.SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10184 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.*
This is coming out.

I declared permission as :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission

Comment: Sorry Sir I re-ask  again, And Thanks for answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Android 6.0, you need to explicitly ask the user to grant the permissions. Just declaring it in the manifest isn't enough.

This [article](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) in the docs is a great place to start learning the new model, but I'll give a brief summary.

Every time you perform an action that requires a "dangerous permission," you need to check if the permission is currently granted, because the user can revoke it at any time.

This can be done with the `checkSelfPermission` method.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We do not have this permission. Let's ask the user
}
```

You can request the permission with the `requestPermissions` method, as such

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_READ_STATE);
```

Where `PERMISSION_READ_STATE` is a constant integer defined by you to check in the callback method later.

You will then override `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your activity and see if the permission was granted. If it was, you can go ahead and preform the dangerous action.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_READ_STATE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission granted!
                // you may now do the action that requires this permission
            } else {
                // permission denied
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, Is it possible without disturbing user?

Comment: Nope, from 6.0 onward we have to ask the user directly. If you're more curious about why this is the direction Android is going, you might watch this video from Google: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f17qe9vZ8RM

Comment: Is there a list of permissions that needs to be asked explicitly?

Comment: Any permissions that are considered "dangerous". See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String device_unique_id,IMEI;


    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 0;


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
    public void GetImei(View view)
    {



        loadIMEI();

    }

    public void loadIMEI() {
        // Check if the READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already available.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
//                get_imei_data();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
            }
        } else {

            TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();
            device_unique_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            textView.setText(device_unique_id+"----"+mngr.getDeviceId());
            // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.
            Toast.makeText(this,"Alredy granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
       @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {

            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

//                Toast.makeText(this,"Alredy DONE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();
                device_unique_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                textView.setText(device_unique_id+"----"+mngr.getDeviceId());

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"ehgehfg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent Rajasimman! Very good and it works as it should! Thank you!! .)