# Is there any alternative way for getting IMEI number which wont give me obsolete warning?

Tags: xamarin.forms, imei, obsolete

Hi I want to get **IMEI number** in my Android device.**And I'm able to do it**. But **I'm getting obsolete warning** saying '**TelephonyManager.DeviceId' is obsolete:'deprecated'**.  I'm using this code to get IMEI number in my Android device

```
Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);

        return mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
```

right now I'm able to disable the obsolete warning by using

```
     mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            return mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
```

But why I'm getting this obsolete warning? Is there a different approach for getting IMEI number where I wont get this obsolete warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Definition](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager.DeviceId/) of `DeviceId`:

```
Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.
```

When `IMEI` is simply:

```
IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity)
```

From [Android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId()) it seems that `DeviceId` is deprecated from API level 26 and that you should use [GetMeid(int slotIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getMeid()) instead. In this case I would check the API level and if it is bellow 26 than I would still use `DeviceId` otherwise `GetMeid(int slotIndex)`.

Something like this:

```
string GetIMEI()
{
    Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        // TODO: Some phones has more than 1 SIM card or may not have a SIM card inserted at all
        return mTelephonyMgr.GetMeid(0);
    else
        #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
        return mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
        #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this exception Java.Lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 11592 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. while i try to get my IMEI

Comment: Please pay attention to the links to official documentation that are part of my answer. DeviceId and GetMeid clearly state that they require a READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

Comment: I already have permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> in my android manifest still it is showing this exception.

Comment: Take a look on existing threads like https://stackoverflow.com/q/35319702/1970317

Comment: I was able to fix it.