# checkpermission runtime for get sim card number in kotlin android?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to get simcard number in kotlin android

In this code I can not get permission box and the toast only displays message, not any phome number

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var wantPermission = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val number = getMyPhoneNO()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "My Phone No is: $number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Log.v("Debug", number)

    }

    private fun getMyPhoneNO(): String {
        val mTelephonyMgr: TelephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        if (checkSelfPermission(this, wantPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return ""
        }
        return mTelephonyMgr.line1Number
    }
}
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319702/android-m-permission-of-the-tested-read-phone-statedangerous-permissions

Comment: this is not working